Nginx: Pass requests to different localhost ports based on server name
I need to pass requests to different localhost ports based on server names using nginx.
Developers already have /etc/hosts files that look like this:
127.0.0.1 site1.local
127.0.0.1 site2.local
127.0.0.1 site3.local
# etc...

To serve these sites locally, developers also have a single Apache instance running with a vhost for each site.
We are replacing the single Apache instance with an instance of nginx for each site. To prevent port collisions, the sites have increasing port numers:

localhost:8001
localhost:8002
localhost:8003
etc

Accessing these sites via localhost:port works fine.
However, we still need to be able to access the sites using site1.local, site2.local, and so on.
I added a new instance of nginx running on port 80 to catch all requests to the site1/2/3.local-named addresses. My desire is for this instance of nginx to pass requests through to the appropriate host based on the server name:

site1.local passes requests to localhost:8001
site2.local passes requests to localhost:8002
site3.local passes requests to localhost:8003
etc

How can I achieve this in the instance of nginx listening to port 80?

This question is similar to: Configure Nginx as reverse proxy with upstream SSL. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In addition to numerous questions about configuring Nginx as reverse proxy on this site, the fine manual is a very good starting point. This site is not intended as a replacement for documentation.

Read how Nginx processes a request and you will see that it is designed to split server names across multiple server blocks.
